# How to change the affiliated authors?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, authorship

I received an email from a journal to confirm my contribution to a manuscript that was submitted by my colleague, and I am the first author in that paper. In this email, there were two links; one for (yes, I am affiliated) and the other for (No, I am not affiliated), and I clicked by mistake on the second link, and my contribution to the manuscript was removed. What can I do to be affiliated to the manuscipt?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contact the editor **as soon as possible** and get your mistake rectified.

If you have waited too long then it may not be possible for the versions already made public.